# what does the __insn_seqb() and __insn_ctz mean?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, macros, glibc

I was reading the `Linux/arch/tile/lib/strlen_32.c` to know about the accomplishment of the `strlen_32`. However I met two `macro`s named `__insn_seqb` and `__insn_ctz` which I didn't know the meaning. The function `strlen_32` is below:

```
size_t strlen(const char*s)
{
    const uintptr_t s_int = (uintptr_t)s;
    const uint32_t *p = (const uint32_t*)(s_int&-4);
    uint32_t v = *p | ((1<<(s_int<<3))-1);
    uint32_t bits;
    while((bits=__insn_seqb(v,0))==0)
         v = *++p;
    return ((const char*)p)+(__insn_ctz(bits)>>3)-s;
 }
```

I searched them on Google, but only found another macro definition:
`#define CFZ(x) __insn_ctz(x)` in `string_endian.h` [glib-ports string-endian.h](https://fossies.org/dox/glibc-ports-2.16.0/string-endian_8h_source.html#l00028)
Could someone tell me where the clear definition is or the real meaning and usage of these two macros?

Comment: It has to do with processing four bytes of the string at once.

Comment: All this dancing due to unaligned access to the data. Not all architectures can do that. In modern kernel we have a helper `get_unaligned()` for that. On the other hand the performance impact could be visible when working on strings at maximum data bus width. See, for example, `strscpy()` implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They seem to be instruction intrinsics for [Tilera processors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilera).

I would guess that `__insn_ctz` is a "count trailing zeroes" instruction.

`__insn_seqb` seems to be testing for a 0 byte within a 4 byte word.

The Tilera instruction is apparently [somewhat similar to MIPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515358/what-instruction-set-is-used-by-tilera-microprocessors#6533251).